# Wrong title displayed in api.stackexchange.com/docs pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, api

The title displayed in all [api.stackexchange.com/docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), per-site methods, pages contains an HTML tag for the "method" (aka GET), and this tag is displayed in the title of the document.

Example for [docs/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers)'s page:

[image: Screenshot showing that the title contains HTML span tag.]

The problem seems to be that all the content of the `<h1>` tag is used as the page title. The text of the HTTP method (GET) is contained in the `<h1>` (see screenshot below) and contains a  tag to stylize the text (blue background).

[image: Screenshot showing that the title is the content of <code><h1></code> tag.]

Answer (score 7):

This should be fixed now. The `<h1>` title tag in the browser tab does not render HTML.